# newbie error on installing python on OS X Lion via brew

Tags: python, osx-lion

I get this error when running on OX Lion:

```
brew install python  

Error: MD5 mismatch
Expected: c8cfcfd42ec9ab900fb3960a3308eef2
Got: f783444754861f9b33e9f4083bd97b60
Archive: /Users/jt/Library/Caches/Homebrew/distribute-0.6.21.tar.gz
(To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.)
```

I remove file but same issue comes up with same hash value

The specific issue is mentioned here https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/7768

I guess I'm not understanding what the workaround is. Can someone explain to me what to do?

I'm using this method to get MySQLdb installed via [mysql-python installation problems (on mac os x lion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335853/mysql-python-installation-problems-on-mac-os-x-lion) ; the bottom part. If better ideas for getting python / mysql working - let me know

thx for any help

Comment: did you try brew update?

Comment: thx - that was it. first time using brew (obviously)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They simply replaced the MD5 value in Python formula. Try 'brew update' command and see if it works after that.

If all else fails you can edit the file yourself locally.

```
vi /usr/local/Library/Formula/python.rb
```

Just make the same change as outlined in diff:

https://github.com/martinploeger/homebrew/commit/0bf86f684fa97a15d6863c3bfe4a75d87c73b7d8

Comment: The answer is right, along with the github link, BUT, the path to formula is wrong. This is the python formula path, not distribute. Careful with that. Just change it for
    vi /usr/local/Library/Formula/distribute.rb