# Installing MySQLdb package for Python on lion

Tags: python, mysql, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql-python installation problems (on mac os x lion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335853/mysql-python-installation-problems-on-mac-os-x-lion)

I know this question is similar to other questions people have asked but I could't find my answer after searching so please bear with me.

I installed Django fine, now I am installing MySQLdb package, but given the code below:

```
!/usr/bin/env python

import os

import sys

from setuptools import setup, Extension

if not hasattr(sys, "hexversion") or sys.hexversion < 0x02030000:
    raise Error("Python 2.3 or newer is required")

if os.name == "posix":
    from setup_posix import get_config

else: # assume windows
    from setup_windows import get_config

metadata, options = get_config()

metadata['ext_modules'] = [Extension(sources=['_mysql.c'], **options)]

metadata['long_description'] = metadata['long_description'].replace(r'\n', '')
setup(**metadata)
```

I get the error that setuptools does not exists ... and I tried changing the path but I can't even find where python is storing my modules and packages ... site-packages folder under Python is empty, except for a README ...

Any help is appreciated.
This is for Python 2.7 btw on LION OS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to install package called "setuptools". If you  use [macports](http://www.macports.org/) you can execute (for python 2.7):

```
sudo port install py27-setuptools
```

in your terminal.