# Is there a MSSql driver for Mac OS X for Python

Tags: python, macos, sql-server-2008

I'm developing a python application on a mac but our company uses MS SQL Server.  Is there a way I can connect to the DB, via python, on the mac?

I'm on Lion with Python 2.7. It's MS SQL Server 2008.

Thanks

Comment: This might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335853/mysql-python-installation-problems-on-mac-os-x-lion

Comment: That user used MySQL, not MSSql (Microsoft Server).  Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a version of FreeTDS (Sybase/Microsoft T-SQL database driver) for Mac OS.

You could compile yourself, or there might possibly be a Mac version already (haven't looked into this myself, but the first place I would check would be MacPorts or Homebrew).

Once installed it would be a matter of configuring Python to use it:

http://www.tryolabs.com/Blog/2012/06/25/connecting-sql-server-database-python-under-ubuntu/

I see this is a few years late, but still wanted to drop it.